Правильно ли здесь составлены предложении?
Первое:

У меня одногруппник в Москву программистом устроился 2 года назад. В
салон цветов.

Второе:

Да, я тоже периодически себе смотрю подработку на фрилансе, по
дизайну.

Есть варианты, как составить данные предложения более правильнее?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Правильно ли здесь составлены предложения?
Нет.
Почему?

У меня одногруппник в Москву программистом устроился 2 года назад. В
салон цветов.

"У меня одногруппник" с каких пор дела одногруппников ваши? И "в Москву" не устраиваются программистом.

Да, я тоже периодически себе смотрю подработку на фрилансе, по
дизайну.

Тут "себе" излишне; подработку не смотрят, её ищут; подработки "на фрилансе" не бывает, это не какая-то биржа с заказами.
Есть варианты, как составить данные предложения правильнее?
Первое:
Мой одногруппник два года назад устроился на работу программистом в московском салоне цветов.
Второе:
Да, я тоже хочу стать фрилансером, периодически ищу работу для дизайнеров.
